# Dark Pool Midpoint Order Matching

Tags: orderbook

From what I understand, orders in some dark pools are typically matched at the midpoint price, and matching prioritized in size, price, time.

Market orders execute at the midpoint.

Limit orders execute at the midpoint only if the midpoint is equal to or better than the specified limit price.

Given the aforementioned criteria, consider the following dark pool orderbook...

| Buy Qty | Buy Px | Sell Px | Sell Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 200 | 10.20 | 10.25 | 300 |
| 100 | 10.15 | 10.30 | 500 |
| 400 | 10.10 | 10.35 | 200 |
| 300 | 10.05 | 10.40 | 100 |

The midpoint price of the dark orderbook is calculated as follows using the top of the orderbook; i.e.
(10.20 + 10.25) / 2 = 10.225

However, dark orderbooks obtain their midpoint price from visible orderbooks, and match orders based on the visible orderbook's midpoint price.

Questions:

1. Do the Buy orders only match at the midpoint price, or can they match lower than the midpoint price ?
2. Do the Sell orders only match at the midpoint price, or can they match higher than the midpoint price ?
3. If a Buy Market order with quantity 500 was entered, which Sell order(s) would it match against, and at what price ?
4. If a Buy Limit order with quantity 500 and price 10.30 was entered, which Sell order(s) would it match against, and at what price ?
5. What other examples of new Buy orders entered into this orderbook would cause matches ?

Comment: Each execution facility is different.  There is not a general answer for these questions.  In the US, the execution rules are proposed and approved by regulators before the facility begins (or modifies) operation.  Those filings would be good source documents for you.  Then, verify with test orders.  Specs and implementations are not the same thing. Better still, make friends with the software development team at the facility for access to its backstory and microstructure quirks. Order instructions (beyond quantity and price) on the sitting limit orders will impact the execution too.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/quant/comments/137v3l1/dark_pool_midpoint_order_matching/